# JavaFX: Trouble binding properties to panes

Tags: java, javafx

I am a beginner who just recently started learning JavaFX, and I seem to be making the same reoccurring mistake within my programs. For example, in the following code I am trying to draw the X-Axis and Y-Axis and have it binded to half the width and height of the pane. When executed, the axes are very small and located at the topleft corner, but as you resize the window of the application, the axes slowly increase in size until the window not being resized anymore.

```
public class Debug extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Pane pane = new Pane();
        GraphFunc test = new GraphFunc();
        pane.getChildren().add(test);

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 500, 500);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}

class GraphFunc extends Pane {
    private double xAxisSpan, yAxisSpan;

    public GraphFunc() {
        xAxisSpan = 100;
        yAxisSpan = 100;
        drawAxes();
    }

    private void drawAxes() {
        Line xAxis = new Line(0, 50, 100, 50);
        Line yAxis = new Line(50, 0, 50, 100);
        xAxis.setStartX(0);
        xAxis.startYProperty().bind(heightProperty().divide(2));
        xAxis.endXProperty().bind(widthProperty());
        xAxis.endYProperty().bind(heightProperty().divide(2));

        yAxis.startXProperty().bind(widthProperty().divide(2));
        yAxis.setStartY(0);
        yAxis.endXProperty().bind(widthProperty().divide(2));
        yAxis.endYProperty().bind(heightProperty());

        getChildren().addAll(xAxis, yAxis);
    }
}
```

I am confused because when pane is change to a StackPane, this does not happen. Also if I moved the code in drawAxes() to start() and added the lines to pane it would also not do this. Please explain, I cannot seem to understand what is happening after researching and playing around with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because of Pane. Pane is meant to be used when absolute positioning of children is required.

This is from Oracle documentation:

> This class may be used directly in cases where absolute positioning of children is required since it does not perform layout beyond resizing resizable children to their preferred sizes. It is the application's responsibility to position the children since the pane leaves the positions alone during layout.

```
    Pane pane = new Pane();
    GraphFunc test = new GraphFunc();
    pane.getChildren().add(test);

    Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 500, 500);
```

If you remove the width and height from the scene and instead set the width and height directly on to test like this:

```html
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        GridPane pane = new GridPane();
        GraphFunc test = new GraphFunc();
        test.setPrefSize(500, 500);
        pane.getChildren().add(test);

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
```

You will get this:

[drawn image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I38Cu.png)

However you will not be able to span.

From Oracle documentation:

> Note: if an application needs children to be kept aligned within a
>   parent (centered, positioned at top-left, etc), it should use a
>   StackPane instead.

Also from Oracle documentation:

> Pane does not clip its content by default, so it is possible that
>   childrens' bounds may extend outside its own bounds, either if
>   children are positioned at negative coordinates or the pane is resized
>   smaller than its preferred size.